# Can fluid be described by a tensor field?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, field-theory, tensor-calculus, flow

In trying to uderstand a tensor field, I am thinking about a fluid. One way to descibe a fluid is by a scalar density function.

Can a (static) fluid also be described by a tensor field (not built out of derivatives of the density function)?

Or would the particles of a fluid have to be more like ellipsoids which could be stretched in various directions (like tidal forces).

i.e. one reprsentation of a tensorfield is by placing an ellipsoid at each point in space.

Or if not a fluid, then perhaps a solid like a rubber sheet (which is often used as an analogy for GR). One could imagine constructing a solid with various tensions in different directions. Would this be desribed by a tensor field?

In other words, which classical object is the simplest example of a tensor field?

Comment: How about the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor)?

Comment: Fluid no, but an elastic solid yes.

Comment: @ggcg what property of the elastic solid makes it different from a fluid?

Comment: molecular bonds.  You will, in general, have different spring constant in each direction.  You can express pressure in a fluid as a tensor but the result is trivial p*id, id = identity tensor.  I think you need to be clear about your assumptions regarding the "fluid", ideal, isentropic, inviscid?  Tiny incompressible ellipsoids packed densely enough would make a granular material which I think is distinct from a fluid.  That may be tensoral in nature, but not fluid.  If your only goal is to find a physical example of a tensor, K is a start.

Comment: This is common in describing strength of material in mechanical engineering, we have stress and strain tensors.